# Scala Spark - copy data from 1 Dataframe into another DF with nested schema & same column names

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

DF1 - flat dataframe with data

```
+---------+--------+-------+                                                    
|FirstName|LastName| Device|
+---------+--------+-------+
|   Robert|Williams|android|
|    Maria|Sharpova| iphone|
+---------+--------+-------+

root
 |-- FirstName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LastName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Device: string (nullable = true)
```

DF2 - empty dataframe with same column names

```
+------+----+
|header|body|
+------+----+
+------+----+

root
 |-- header: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- FirstName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- LastName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- body: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Device: string (nullable = true)
```

DF2 schema Code:

```
val schema = StructType(Array(
StructField("header", StructType(Array(
StructField("FirstName", StringType),
StructField("LastName", StringType)))), 
StructField("body", StructType(Array(
StructField("Device", StringType))))
))
```

DF2 with data from DF1 would be the final output.

Need to do this for multiple columns for a complex schema and make it configurable. Have to do this without using case class.

---

APPROACH #1 - use schema.fields.map to map DF1 -> DF2?

APPROACH #2 - create a new DF and define data and schema?

APPROACH #3 - use zip and map transformations to define 'select col as col' query.. don't know if this would work for nested (structtype) schema

How would I go on about doing that?

Comment: There is no such a thing as copying one dataframe into another in Spark. Dataframes, similarly to RDDs, are immutable, please spend some time to understand the importance of immutability in Spark since it is a basic and crucial concept at the same time. The only way to combine value from two dataframes is through join, although in this case you don't have a join condition, neither common columns. Your problem could be expressed better by transforming DF1 into the schema of DF2. One way to implement that is using `struct` as nicely shown below by @mvasyliv

Answer (score 1):

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val sourceDF = Seq(
  ("Robert", "Williams", "android"),
  ("Maria", "Sharpova", "iphone")
).toDF("FirstName", "LastName", "Device")

val resDF = sourceDF
  .withColumn("header", struct('FirstName, 'LastName))
  .withColumn("body", struct(col("Device")))
  .select('header, 'body)

resDF.printSchema
//  root
//  |-- header: struct (nullable = false)
//  |    |-- FirstName: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- LastName: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- body: struct (nullable = false)
//  |    |-- Device: string (nullable = true)

resDF.show(false)
//  +------------------+---------+
//  |header            |body     |
//  +------------------+---------+
//  |[Robert, Williams]|[android]|
//  |[Maria, Sharpova] |[iphone] |
//  +------------------+---------+
```